# CSS remove border right of the .selected-item div and conjunction main div

Tags: css

Hi I want to remove the right border of the list and the left border of the main div using css, I think it can be achieve using `after` if css but still some help implementing it.

```
import { makeStyles } from '@utils/styles'
export const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({

selectedTeam: {
  background: '#FFFFFF',
  borderLeft: '3px solid #AA1E1E',
  borderRight: '0px',
  // '&::after': {
  //   content: '"helloehhe"',
  // },
  },
}))
```

current output    [image]

what I want to achieve [image]

Comment: Try border-right -> none property.

Comment: not working, just a note this is 2 div with one for side bar and one for main.
if one div is selectedTeam remove border right of that div and left border of the main div (just the height of the selected div)

Comment: Try to remove Outline and box shadow